# Access property of a class in typescript via string for sort

Tags: typescript

The problem is simple, in javascript I can have an object as this one

```
var obj={
    par1:'value1',
    par2:'value2'
}
```

And I can access to the values in this ways `obj['par1']` is it possible to do the same thing in `TypeScript` with a class like this:

```
export class obj{
    par1:string;
    par2:string;
}

this.obj['par1']=value1
```

### Update

This is the **Documents** class

```
export class Documents {
    par1: string
    par2: string
    constructor(par1: string,
        par2: string
    ){
        this.par1=par1
        this.par2=par2
    }
}
```

And this is my attempt:

```
private docs:Documents[]=new Documents[
    new Documents('value1','value2'),
    new Documents('value3','value4')
];
sort(ordertype:string,property:string){
    for(let doc of this.docs){
        for(let field in doc)
            console.log(doc[field])
    }
}
```

And this is an error:

> [ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

I've even tried to cast it to string but nothing.

## Update 2

I've saw the error, I corrected it, the code above is correct and works.

Comment: Did you try it? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: where instance of this class created?

Comment: Ok sorry it was a generic question, in attempt to get some information on typescript and understand the difference between the javascript objects an typescript classes

Comment: done it and the exception is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't create the `Documents` array properly, it should be like this:

```
let docs: Documents[] = [];
docs.push(new Documents('value1', 'value2'));
docs.push(new Documents('value3', 'value4'));
```

or

```
let docs: Documents[] = [new Documents('value1', 'value2'), new Documents('value3', 'value4')];
```

If you do that then your code works fine, check it out [in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Documents%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20par1%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20par2%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(par1%3A%20string%2C%20par2%3A%20string)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.par1%20%3D%20par1%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.par2%20%3D%20par2%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20docs%3A%20Documents%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5Bnew%20Documents('value1'%2C%20'value2')%2C%20new%20Documents('value3'%2C%20'value4')%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20sort(ordertype%3Astring%2Cproperty%3Astring)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for(let%20doc%20of%20this.docs)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for(let%20field%20in%20doc)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(doc%5Bfield%5D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D).

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `console.log(doc[field])` with `console.log((doc as any)[field])`